# Como dividir arquivo para importação

Tags: php, mysql

Tenho um arquivo que não tem separação de dados e preciso inseri-lo no banco de dados, como posso fazer a importação dele.

Por exemplo, o arquivo esta assim:

```
931398401312
```

Quero dividi-lo em 4 colunas, exemplo:

```
|column1|column2|column3|column4|
|931    |3984   |01     |312    |
```

Meu código:

```
$arquivo_tmp = $_FILES['arquivo']['tmp_name'];

$dados = file($arquivo_tmp);

foreach($dados as $linha){
    $linha = trim($linha);
    $valor = explode(',', $linha);
    var_dump($valor);

    $column1 = $valor[0];
    $column2 = $valor[1];
    $column3 = $valor[2];
    $column4 = $valor[3];

    $result_usuario = "INSERT INTO teste (column1, column2, column3, column4) VALUES ('$column1', '$column2', '$column3', '$column4')";

    $resultado_usuario = mysqli_query($conn, $result_usuario);  
}
```

Comment: Qual é o padrão da divisão?  É sempre 3, 4, 2 e 3 números? ou isso pode mudar?

Comment: Sim, o padrão é este.

Comment: basicamente `substr( $linha, $coluna, $largura )` - mais detalhes no link acima - Exemplo: no seu caso: `$column3 = substr( $linha, 7, 2 );`

Comment: @Bacco eu preciso criar uma variável $linha para cada coluna? tipo $linha1 = $column1...

Comment: sim, e cada uma com um valor diferente de início e largura. Dei um exemplo da linha 3 para você ver os valores (começa na posição 7, largura 2)

Comment: Ao invés de $valor vou usar o substr então?

Comment: sim, e não tem nada de explode, e o trim tb não é pra precisar

Comment: Ok, muito obrigado!!!!